# Static is not returning any css or js resources in Grails 1.4

Tags: grails, resources, static

I have just created my first Grails 1.4 application, and am having some problems with the new resourse management: the "static handler" is not returning any css or js files, but instead saying:

```
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/plugins/blueprint-1.0.2/css/blueprint/screen.css
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/css/main.css
ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /static/js/application.js
```

Images are working fine!

As you can see on the below files, I have really scrapped everything off - so I am thinking that I might be missing some general setting somewhere?

The layout file (main.gsp):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <g:layoutTitle/>
      <r:layoutResources/>

   </head>
   <body>
      <g:layoutBody/>
      <r:layoutResources/>
   </body>
</html>
```

The page (index.gsp):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
      <r:require modules="jquery-ui, blueprint"/>
      <r:require module="core"/> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="form"> 
        <r:img uri="/images/grails_logo.png" width="100" height="50"/>
        Hello World
     </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

The output HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/gdw/static/plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <link href="/gdw/static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
        <script src="/gdw/static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.15/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <link href="/gdw/static/plugins/blueprint-1.0.2/css/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
        <!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="/gdw/static/plugins/blueprint-1.0.2/css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
        <link href="/gdw/static/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />  
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="form">
            <img src="/gdw/static/images/grails_logo.png" width="100" height="50" />
            Hello World
        </div>
        <script src="/gdw/static/js/application.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my modules (StaticResources.groovy):

```
modules = {
    core {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        defaultBundle 'ui'
        resource url:'/css/main.css', attrs:[media:'screen']
        resource url:'/js/application.js'
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I tried without requiring the jQuery and blueprint but that didn't change the fact that main.css and application.js still was not found - and the files ARE there!

Answer (score 4):

If you're running on windows, then it looks like you've run into [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-102) [bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPRESOURCES-120) in the resources plugin. There are currently a couple of workarounds:

Add `defaultBundle false` to your module definition

```
core {
    defaultBundle false

    dependsOn 'jquery'
    defaultBundle 'ui'
    resource url:'/css/main.css', attrs:[media:'screen']
    resource url:'/js/application.js'
}
```

Alternatively, try adding the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.resources.debug=true
```

Comment: Thanks! The debug=true helped (the other one didn't). At least I am not stuck now. I will keep watching the bug-report and check when a fix will be released. Hopefully soon! Thanks again :-)

Comment: grails.resources.debug=true this helped me too :) Thanx Don.